# Region highlighting in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

With Visual Studio 2010 block/region highlighting, I find it definitely frustrating when every time my cursor passes it, the whole region is being highlighted.

Does anyone know of a solution?

Comment: welcome to Super User!  Super User is not a discussion forum.  *"do you feel..."* isn't a reasonably answerable, concrete question.  if there's an actual question you'd like to ask (*"can I disable..."*, perhaps), please edit the post to clarify.  then flag it for moderator attention and it can be considered for reopening.

Comment: Tools, Options, Environment, Fonts and Colors. Set "Collapsible Region" to your editor colour.

Comment: @taspeotis Thanks +1 this constant flicking was driving me crazy

Comment: Rephrased the question to be acceptable as a question. taspeotis should add his comment as an answer.

Comment: thanks, was looking for this! @taspeotis: You should add your comment as an answer...

Answer (score 2):

Navigate to `Fonts and Colors` under `Tools, Options, Environment`. Set `Collapsible Region` to your editor colour.